# Change of a textbox.name in a form by code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Form in an Excel VBA project that has many textboxes with names I'd need to change. For instance, names in the projects are: Fees01TBX; Fees02TBX; Fees03TBX, and so on. There are 40 textboxes like these, and I need to change the names into a sequence I can manage better. For instance, I'd need to have them with these names: Expenses01; Expenses02, Expenses03, and so on.

I tried to change it using some code like (just for one textbox):

```
Sub ChgName()    

    MyForm.Fees01TBX.Name = "Expenses01"
    'Doing this for each one would not be a problem, I can array the sequence.
End Sub
```

I think it should possible to change the name of a textbox in a form by code, but how?

Comment: You're trying to change the actual name, not the displayed caption? If so, no, there's no easy way to do this. If your example above worked, it would invalidate itself, since Fees01TBX would no longer exist.

Comment: Yes, this is the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you ticked Trust Access to the VBA Project Object Model in security settings:

```
Sub Rename()
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("MyForm")
        .Designer.Controls("Fees01TBX").Name = "Expenses01"
    End With
End Sub
```

But if Fees01TBX had code you have to change this as well, *but for 40 TextBoxes you could do it manually*

Comment: Thanks @EvR for your answer. I'm trying, but the error message says: Method "VBProject" of object "_Workbook" failed. I am doing something wrong for sure...

Comment: Thanksssss!!!!! I thought I ticked this, but the security settings of my computer cleaned it up. Now I forced it and it works perfectly. Again, thank you so much.